# Get state and country place_id from city using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My goal is to have the following implemented:

- User types "San Fran" in the input form
- My project shows the user: "San Francisco > CA > US"

At this moment I have this:

- User types "San Fran" in the input form
- The project uses Maps Autocomplete API to get "San Fran" data
- This call returns place_id for the city alongside respective country name and state name.
- So I'm planning to use more two Maps Geocode API calls to retrieve the missing place_id's.

My question is:

- Is there any way to get theses three place_id's with a single API call?
- If not, am I using the right API calls to avoid getting wrong data? For example, the same city name appears in more than one state.

Comment: There is no way to get place IDs for address components in one call. It may be an interesting feature request. Feel free to raise the FR at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/. Autocomplete definitely is  the correct way to avoid wrong data.

Comment: Please, support the feature request to get this API available: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=apitype%3APlacesAPI%20type%3AEnhancement%20place_id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars&groupby=&sort=-stars&id=8982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really seems there's no way to get the result I'm looking for in a single call at this moment.

There is a open feature request at this link:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=apitype%3APlacesAPI%20type%3AEnhancement%20place_id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars&groupby=&sort=-stars&id=8982

Please vote up if you're looking for the same thing as me!